# How can ProGuard keep class implements clause(class signature)

Tags: android, proguard, parcelable

I have a class implementing Android `Parcelable`, and it has a field named `CREATOR` which implementing `Parcelable.Creator`. I could let ProGuard keep the `CREATOR` field by following config:

```
-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    static ** CREATOR;
}
```

But I don't know how to let ProGuard keep the `CREATOR` anonymous class signature, because of that, the obfuscated class of the `CREATOR` anonymous implementation looks like below:

```
final class i extends Object
```

We can see that it losts the `implements Parcelable.Creator` signature, so when I launch my app, it crashed with the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.github.piasy.model.b.b.i cannot be 
cast to android.os.Parcelable$Creator
```

I know that I could let ProGuard to keep all inner class(so the `Parcelable.Creator` implementation won't be obfuscated at all), but I want to know could I just keep the class signature (`implements Parcelable.Creator` part).

I've tried `-keepattributes Signature`, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for https://github.com/zhenghuiy, this problem is solved after half year.

It turns out that after update my Android build tools, this problem disappears, no need for below configuration too:

```
-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    static ** CREATOR;
}
```